# Layering multiple DIV objects: CSS position top works in firebug but doesn't load with page

Tags: html, css

I need to layer multiple `div`objects.
To look like this
[image]

Whenever I load the markup as an HTML file in the browser the `top:` feature isn't responding. Then, if I open firebug to check the CSS, it shows that the value is there. If I modify the value of top: then and only then do the elements with `top` applied to them snap to the value in the CSS file.

I am aware that an alternative is to use a negative margin-top combined with padding set in fixed units, but as margin-top is relative to the child and not the parent that isn't consistent under all circumstances. I'd rather use `position:absolute` inside of a `position:relative` container.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqd3x91q/), for some reason the it isn't congruent with what I see on my html file. Nonetheless, it may be of some help visualizing things.

```
<!--here's the container-->
<div id="fale_container">

<!--here's the container for the top-layer-->
<div id="fale_textbox_0">
<div class="highlight0a" id="Fale"><h1 class="fale_heading" id="faleh1">Fale</h1></div>
<div class="highlight0a" id="que"><h1 class="fale_heading">que</h1></div>
<div class="highlight0a" id="nem"><h1 class="fale_heading">nem</h1></div>
<div class="highlight0a" id="um"><h1 class="fale_heading">um</h1></div>
</div>

<!--here's the markup in question, this needs to go behind the container cited above. this is where the problematic styles are located-->
<div id=fale_textbox_container>
    <div id="fale_textbox_2">
        <h1 id="fale_heading_2">Rápido</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="fale_textbox_3">
        <h2 id="fale_subheading_2">Sem Sotaque</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fale_textbox_1">
        <h2 id="fale_subheading_1">GRINGO</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.highlight0a{
    position: relative;
    height: 55.7px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}

.fale_heading {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 13.32756%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.00666%;
  margin-left: 13.33422%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  clear: right;
  z-index: 10; }

#fale_container {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%; }

#fale, #que, #nem, #um {
  z-index: 9; }

#fale:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 9%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 13.334%;
  min-width: 4em; }

#que:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 9.1%;
  left: 13.334%;
  min-width: 6em; }

#nem:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10.5%;
  left: 13.334%;
  min-width: 4em; }

#um:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 7.3%;
  left: 13.334%;
  min-width: 2em; }

#fale_textbox_container, #fale_textbox_1, #fale_textbox_2, #fale_textbox_3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: auto; }

#fale_textbox_container {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 0; }

#fale_textbox_1, #fale_textbox_2, #fale_textbox_3 {
  padding: 2%;
  top: -42%;
  z-index: 2; }

#fale_textbox_1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white; }

#fale_textbox_2 {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #7C1A1A; }

#fale_textbox_3 {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #3F3C3C; }

#fale_heading_2, #fale_subheading_1, #fale_subheading_2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 13.32756%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.00666%;
  margin-left: 28.66858%;
  color: black; }

#fale_heading_2 {
  top: 10; }

#fale_subheading_1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  top: 10; }

#fale_subheading_2 {
  top: 10; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Maybe you mean the following:

```
#fale_textbox_container {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute; // Added this one
}

.highlight0a {
    position: relative;
    height: 55.7px;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    display: inline; // And this one
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqd3x91q/3/

And next time, please please outline the code a little bit better, hard to read. And sometime in English would give most users more feeling of what you are trying to do. For me it looks like it is some sort of book cover.